# Laravel 5.4 relationship doesnt work cant attach second parameter

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've got some problems making relationship between my user who is logged in and events that he wants to join work.
I am really taking many steps to do something similar to what I do with role users. But here I have some problems, because my **user** uses model User, **events** uses model HomeModel and 3 other models to make a relation and connecte to table SaveEvent.
There is my code. I hope someone can tell me how to figure it out because I wasted 2 days to resolve my problem:

**Model HomeModel**

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HomeModel extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'events'; // you may change this to your name table
 public $timestamps = true; // set true if you are using created_at and updated_at
 protected $primaryKey = 'id'; // the default is id
     
      /**
     * Is it an all day event?
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAllDay()
    {
        return (bool)$this->day;
    } 
    
    
}
```

**Model User**

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{ 
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'lastname', 'name', 'phonenumber', 'email', 'password', 'user_id' ,
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    
         public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'user_role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\SaveEvent')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Model SaveEvent**

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SaveEvent extends Model
{
 
    public function users()
    {
       
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }  
}
```

**Table to relationship**

```html
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| users_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| events_id  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Controller ZapisController**

```html
    public function acceptEvent($id)
      {
 
        $events_id = HomeModel::find($id);
        $users_id = new SaveEvent;
        $users_id->users_id=Auth::id();
        $users_id->save();
        $users_id->events()->attach($events_id);

        return redirect()->back();
      }
```

Comment: there is no events relationship in SaveEvent so this cannot work: $users_id->events() since $users_id is an instance of SaveEvent

Comment: ok so i should do this with homemodel but homemodel use table for event and i dont know how attach this

Comment: is `HomeModel` an event? Your class seems to say it is, but it doesn't make sense. Use sensible names so people can understand what you're doing. At any rate https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations may be of help

Comment: ye i know name was bad but know i dont want change this ;p and  yes homemodel is for events for showing it on home web thats why i named like that and i read i cant do 1 model for 2 tables;/ and i dont know how do this

Comment: https://github.com/K3n0s/szpital/tree/paneladmina   maybe this will helpfull for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a model to save `events`. This is a many to many relationship with so use a pivot table.

Change `event` method in `User` model like this :

```
 public function events()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(HomeModel::class,'PIVOT_TABLE_NAME','user_id','events_id');->withTimestamps();
    }
```

and in `HomeModel` :

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'PIVOT_TABLE_NAME','events_id','user_id');
    }
```

now you can use `$user->events->attach($events_id);`

Comment: still dont work i got this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'events_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `save_events` (`users_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3, 2017-03-27 11:19:50, 2017-03-27 11:19:50))

Comment: its look like still cant attach this becouse it doesnt find events_id column

Comment: don't forget you must use User model not user_id variable

Comment: $users_id = new User;  like that? becouse its not work

Comment: something like `$user = Auth:user();` for user and `$event = HomeModel::find($id);` for event . now use `$user->events()->attach($events_id);`

Comment: $event = HomeModel::find($id);
        $user = new User; 
        $user=Auth::id();
        $user->save();
        $user->events->attach($event);

Comment: I got this error: Call to a member function save() on integer

Comment: `$user = new User()` made new user. if you want get login user just use `$user = Auth::user()` that return current user (without `$user->save()` line);

Comment: its almost working;p the query pivot is making but i got problem with attach now 
Method attach does not exist.
Controller look now:         
$event = HomeModel::find($id);       
$user = Auth::user();
$user->events->attach($event);

Comment: Use events method with parentheses `$user->events()->attach($event);`